# Difference between Cloudant and Cloudant Dedicated

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Have two questions with respect to Cloudant.

1. What is the difference between 'Cloudant' and 'Cloudant Dedicated'?
2. Noticed the 'Shared Dedicated' against the 'Cloudant Dedicated'; is 'Shared Dedicated' a single-tenant?

Comment: Can you share a link to the documentation you are looking at?

Answer (score 1):

Cloudant is most likely referring to public Cloudant which you can [provision and use today in Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db/).

You can browse the plans [here](https://docs.cloudant.com/bluemix.html#bluemix-public).

Bluemix Dedicated provides physically isolated hardware in an IBM data center. A single tenant Bluemix environment is created for you on a combination of bare metal and virtual machines.

Cloudant DBaaS Enterprise on single tenant dedicated hardware is available in a Bluemix Dedicated configuration.

Shared usually refers to a multi-tenant Cloudant cluster.

Comment: Hi @user7981462, did this answer your question?